# Would it be possible to force the pineal gland to release dimethyltryptamine on command?

Tags: brain

To my knowledge, the pineal gland is responsible for the release of dimethyltryptamine (DMT) upon death.  Would it be possible to force the pineal gland to release this DMT while still living?

Answer (score 3):

According to this [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineal_gland) the release of DMT upon death is speculative and its presence has so far been confirmed in rodents brain and human melanoma cell line [SK-Mel-147](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimethyltryptamine). DMT is also produced in humans; however, its production and purpose in the brain has yet to be proven or understood (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimethyltryptamine). Hence from what I have gathered on the matter DMT has not yet been proven to get secreted from human pineal gland and its command based secretion is yet to be discovered.

Comment: Personal research on 4chan has revealed a group of people who believe that DMT is a molecule responsible for spirituality and that the pineal gland has some sort of supernatural/psychic function. They also believe that fluoridation of water is a government conspiracy to calcify the populations' pineal glands and cut off that supernatural function. Just thought I should warn you where these questions come from in case we get more.